# Dates in shorthand

Tags: c#

Let's say you have a date string like follows:

```
11/15/2010, 12/1/10, 12/2/10, 12/3/10, 12/4/10, 12/9/10
```

How would you shorten this string like follows (or something similar)

```
11/15/2010, 12/1-4, 9/10
```

Because imagine 30 days in a row it would be better to see 12/1-31/10 than have all dates listed.

Just to make it a little more compact?

Comment: I assume we are looking at dates in US English format?

Comment: right, or if there is a way for any format that is welcomed to.

Comment: I'm not seeing the shortening pattern.  Where did 11/1/2010 come from?  And 9/10 is the month and year of the last date in the input, while the previous entry in the output is a month and range of days.

Comment: did you mean for output to be: 11/15/10, 12/1-4/2010, 12/9/10

Comment: @Conrad - that would be fine too. 12/1-4,9/10 was just a shortened version of that.

Comment: For whom is this intended?  This is really a "would my customer like this..." question.

Comment: @rod: that's some extreme shorthand...never seen it before.

Comment: See this possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852675/c-writing-time-through-two-dates-as-string

Comment: @rod oh so if read aloud it would be "December first to the fourth and the ninth of two-thousand and ten"

Comment: @caveman - that is correct it will be on a pdf report for a customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class so_4413380
{
    private class DateGroup
    {
        public IList<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }

        public DateTime First
        {
            get { return Dates.OrderBy(d => d).FirstOrDefault(); }
        }

        public DateTime Last
        {
            get { return Dates.OrderBy(d => d).LastOrDefault(); }
        }

        public DateGroup()
        {
            Dates = new List<DateTime>();
        }
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        var dateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat;
        var dates = new[] { "11/15/2010", "12/1/10", "12/2/10", "12/3/10", "12/4/10", "12/9/10" };
        var realDates = dates.Select(s => DateTime.Parse(s, dateTimeFormat));
        var dateGroups = new List<DateGroup>();

        DateTime lastDate = DateTime.MinValue;
        foreach (var date in realDates.OrderBy(d => d))
        {
            if (date.Month == lastDate.Month && (date - lastDate).Days <= 1)
            {
                var dateGroup = dateGroups.LastOrDefault();
                dateGroup.Dates.Add(date);
            }
            else
            {
                var dateGroup = new DateGroup();
                dateGroups.Add(dateGroup);

                dateGroup.Dates.Add(date);
            }

            lastDate = date;
        }

        foreach (var dateGroup in dateGroups)
        {
            if (dateGroup.Dates.Count == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dateGroup.First.ToString(dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, dateTimeFormat));
            }
            else
            {
                int firstDay = dateGroup.First.Day;
                int lastDay = dateGroup.Last.Day;

                var dateString = dateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.Replace("d", firstDay + "-" + lastDay);

                Console.WriteLine(dateGroup.First.ToString(dateString, dateTimeFormat));
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Produces

```
11/15/2010
12/1-4/2010
12/9/2010
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and a fresh perspective.